# Some methods missing in Calendar class

Tags: codenameone

I want to make use of some methods of java.util.Calendar class like getActualMaximum() and roll() but they are missing in CodenameOne.

Am trying to get maximum day(last day) in a month for some date related calculation.

Please any workaround to this?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I saw what you mean when I `clean and build` my project.

Comment: I undeleted and edited my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

int startDate = 28; 
int maxDayOfMonth = startDate;
int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDate + 1);

while (currentMonth == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
    maxDayOfMonth++;
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, maxDayOfMonth + 1);
}
System.out.println(maxDayOfMonth);
```

**Test:**

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date1 = "2017-02-27";
String date2 = "2017-02-28";
String date3 = "2017-03-01";
String date4 = "2017-04-20";

java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date1)); //Change as neccessary to test others
```